# macosx/Sierra: getting write permissions on /System/Library/CoreServices

Tags: macos, file-permissions

I'm using macosx/Sierra, and I want to get write permissions in the `/System/Library/CoreServices` folder. I set myself to root via `sudo`, and all the directories in the tree have `drwxr-xr-x` permissions, but I still can't write in that directory.

```
% sudo -s
# cd /System/Library/CoreServices
# pwd
/System/Library/CoreServices
# whoami
root
# ls -ld .
0 drwxr-xr-x  160 root  wheel  5440 Feb 14 10:00 ./
# touch x
touch: x: Operation not permitted
```

Is there any way I can enable write access on this directory as `root`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS Sierra (a.k.a. 10.12) introduced *System Integrity Protection*. This makes wide swaths of the startup filesystem (mostly `/System/...`) immutable. It doesn't matter if you have root access or not.

There are a couple of ways to get around it.

- Boot from a different startup volume; SIP only protects the current
  startup volume.
- Turn SIP off using the `csrutil` tool

Note that you'll still need to boot from a different startup volume to disable SIP, as the `csrutil` can't turn it off for the startup volume. (Tip: booting into the recovery volume is a quick way to accomplish this.) But personally, I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can enable write access on this directory as root?

No, unless you disable the SIP as already mentioned by James Bucanek, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Further information can be found in Apple's [Support Document] on the topic.(https://support.apple.com/ro-ro/HT204899)

Comment: I can only put a check mark by one answer. Yours is as valuable to me as the other answer.

Comment: Thats OK. Not to worry.